# Nativescript Sidekick Build Release Android - Build failed. Unable to decrypt PKCS#8 ShroudedKeyBag, wrong password?

Tags: android, build, nativescript, keystore, sidekick

I'm trying to build my first application for the play store.
I created a new Keystore with KeyStore Explorer as described in tutorials as a p12 file
I start the build giving it the keystore password and after Upload step completed the error in the title pops up.

Haven't found any solution googling - hope someone can help me

Comment: The error pops up in Playstore itself right after upload or it happens at runtime when you install the app from Playstore?

Comment: nono this happened when i want to build the app with sidekick and cloud build!

Comment: Did you use PEPK tool to create your key? Did you give a try for command line?